# Unexpected token: position text in java input stream reader

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to parse xml from a url use pullparser, however I am getting the following error:

Unexpected token (position:TEXT - !!.....in java.io.InputStreamReader)

Here is the code I am using to handle the xml file:

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private Activity context;

        public GetXMLTask(Activity context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String xml = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);
            }
            return xml;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {

            XMLDOMParser parser = new XMLDOMParser();
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
            Document doc = parser.getDocument(stream);

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(NODE_CUST);

            Customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            Customer customer = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                customer = new Customer();
                Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                customer.setId(Integer.parseInt(e.getAttribute(ATTR_ID)));
                customer.setName(parser.getValue(e, NODE_NAME));
                customer.setSurname(parser.getValue(e, NODE_SUR));

                Customers.add(customer);
            }

            listViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context, Customers);
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        }

        /* uses HttpURLConnection to make Http request from Android to download
         the XML file */
        private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {....java
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");

            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                        output.append(s);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Unable to parse URL", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "IO Exception", e);
            }

            return output.toString();
 }
}
```

This line seems to be where the problem is:

```
  Document doc = parser.getDocument(stream);
  The getDocumet(stream) method is throwing the exception:

   public Document getDocument(InputStream inputStream) {
    Document document = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);

        document = db.parse(inputSource);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
    return document;
}
```

The view source of the xml all appears no the same linelike so:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><collection><customer><id>4</id><name>john</name><surname>test</surname></customer><customer><id>6</id><name>test</name><surname>tset</surname></customer><customer><id>8</id><name>test</name><surname>test</surname></customer><customer><id>9</id><name>brian</name><surname>brian</surname></customer><customer><id>10</id><name>test</name><surname>testr</surname></customer><customer><id>11</id><name>hello</name><surname>pass</surname></customer><customer><id>12</id><name>brian2</name><surname>passwords</surname></customer><customer><id>13</id><name>briant</name><surname>pass</surname></customer><customer><id>14</id><name>frank</name><surname>pass</surname></customer></collection>`

Would this have an impact?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might help people if you pointed out which line is throwing the exception. Could you also attach the XML (if not sensitive) and stack trace?

Comment: The error is showing at At org.apache.harmony.xml.parses.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)

Answer (score 1):

first of all check whether ur xml is valid or invalid. using xml online validator. if its is valid then try this

BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream),"UTF-8");

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, I tried changing the buffered reader line but I'm still getting the same problem. This is the xml: <collection>
<customer>
<id>4</id>
<name>john</name>
<surname>test</surname>
</customer>

</collection>

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with enconding. You should define correct charset when creating your InputStreamReader in getXmlFromUrl(). If you already tried suggestion of @omkar and still have the same problem, then you should try others encodings. Have you tried:

- ISO-8859-1
- US-ASCII
- UTF-16
- UTF-16BE
- UTF-16LE
- UTF-8

For example:

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

These are valid in every java implementation.

NOTE that you could control the creation of this XML, then best thing to do would be to DECLARE the charset you're using like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
    <customer>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>john</name>
        <surname>test</surname>
    </customer>
</collection>
```

This way you are sure what charset to use when parsing it. In above example, "UTF-8".

And if everything fails, it may be the weird case of some character that is not part of declared charset.

You could use a less sensitive decoder, like this:

```
CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, decoder));
```

And it should just ignore the error.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm still getting the same error, I created the xml     and the charset is UTF-8. The problem seems to be with the document builder